# Choice field for multiple items in a field

Tags: django, django-models

If i have 5 diffent sport in Sports then in Intrest model i want to put level to each of those 5 sports seprately,and want to print.How to do it.
exampl:cricket=Advance
basketball=beginer

```
            class Sports(models.Model):

                Sport=models.CharField(max_length=30)

            class User(models.Model):
                user=models.CharField(max_length=30)

            class Intrest(models.Model):
                user_name=models.Foreignkey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
                sport=models.Foreignkey(Sports,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
                LEVEL=(
                    ('1','Beginer'),
                    ('2','Intermediate'),
                    ('3','Advance'),
                    ('4','Nevel Played'),
                            )
                Level=models.CharField(max_length=30,choices=LEVEL)
```

Comment: In your `Sports` model, could you define a foreign key relationship with your `Intrest` model? For example, `intrest = models.ForeignKey("Intrest", on_delete=models.CASCADE)`.

Comment: but how thast would connect to the user

Comment: i simply want ,user fill intrests at once to all the sports,something like that

Comment: Why is the User model a CharField? You don't have to define a User model if you use Django's user model.

Comment: no,i am not using django user

Comment: Do you have a good reason not to? It saves a lot of effort.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this worked for me:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Sports(models.Model):
    sport_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user = models.Foreignkey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Interest(models.IntegerChoices):
        beginner = 1
        intermediate = 2
        advance = 3
        never_played = 4
        level = models.IntegerField(choices=Interest.choices, help_text="How well can you play?")
```

Comment: i am not using django user

Comment: My answer is still valid - just replace user with your own model.

Comment: i am creating an api,i need to implement this over there